# getInitialProps axios header config with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, axios, next.js

How can I satisfy TypeScript here:
I have a problem here

```
<< headers: req?.headers >>, header type does not satisfy ts
```

Please see screenshot below:

[image]

```
Home.getInitialProps = async ({ req }: NextPageContext) => {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
  
    // we are on the server!
    const { data } = await axios.get<State>(
      "http://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local/api/users/currentuser",
      {
        headers: req?.headers,
      }
    );

    return data;
  } 
};
```

Normally I have to change `NextPageContext` or add another type of axios?